# How to call procedure using triggers

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

Table:

```
create table department(deptno number, deptname varchar2(50), deptloc varchar2(50));

insert into department values(1,'A','X');
insert into department values(2,'B','Y');
insert into department values(3,'C','Z');
```

Stored procedure :

```
create or replace procedure secure_dml(i_month IN varchar2)
is

begin
if i_month <> 'March' then
dbms_output.put_line('You can modify or add a department only at the end of a financial year');
else 
--should I write insert/update DML statement?

end;
```

Trigger :

```
create or replace trigger tr_check_dept before insert on department
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Record inserted');
end;
```

Requirement :

Implement the following business rule with the help of a Procedure and a Trigger :-

- i. Changes to the data in the Department table, will be allowed only in the month of March.
- ii. Create a procedure named SECURE_DML that prevents the DML statement from executing in any other month other than March. In case, if a user tries to modify the table in any other month apart from March, the procedure should display a message

  > “You can modify or add a department only at the end of a financial year”
- iii. Create a statement level trigger named TR_CHECK_DEPT on the Department table that calls the above procedure.
- iv. Test it by inserting a new record in the Department table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could do everything within a trigger, but OK - that's some kind of a homework. Here's how I understood it.

Procedure doesn't do anything "smart", just displays the message. Note that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call displays a message, it doesn't prevent anyone to do anything - instead of it, you should `raise_application_error`.

The answer to your question

> should I write insert/update DML statement?

is - in my opinion - **NO**, you shouldn't.

---

Trigger calls that procedure. Yours doesn't check the month, while it should (i.e. move that control from procedure to trigger).

---

Everything put together might look like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure secure_dml
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    raise_application_error(-20000,
  5      'You can modify or add a department only at the end of a financial year');
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace trigger tr_check_dept
  2    before insert on department
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if extract(month from sysdate) <> 3 then
  6       secure_dml;
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into department(deptno, deptname, deptloc)
  2    values (4, 'D', 'W');
insert into department(deptno, deptname, deptloc)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: You can modify or add a department only at the end of a financial year
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.SECURE_DML", line 4
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TR_CHECK_DEPT", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TR_CHECK_DEPT'


SQL>
```

---

Just for testing purposes, as it is September today, let's modify trigger code so that it works for this month (instead of March) and see what `INSERT` does in that case.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger tr_check_dept
  2    before insert on department
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if extract(month from sysdate) <> 9 then      --> this line was changed
  6       secure_dml;
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into department(deptno, deptname, deptloc)
  2    values (4, 'D', 'W');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Right; now it works.